# Можно ли писать несколько условий в JOIN после ON?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Допустим, есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT t.type_condition AS pay, t.type_condition AS orders, 
       t.type_condition AS news, t.type_condition AS other, 
       s.login AS login, s.telephone AS telephone
FROM `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
INNER JOIN `vixen_erps_services_type` t ON t.type_id = s.index2
```

Могу ли я после `ON` написать несколько условий объединения? Например так:

```
SELECT t.type_condition AS pay, t.type_condition AS orders, 
       t.type_condition AS news, t.type_condition AS other, 
       s.login AS login, s.telephone AS telephone
FROM `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
INNER JOIN `vixen_erps_services_type` t ON t.type_id = s.pay, s.orders, s.news, s.other
```

И если не так, то каким образом?
В полях `pay`, `orders`, `news`, `other` таблицы всегда для одного из четырех цифры от 1 до 4, для остальных - 0. Делаю это для того, чтобы вместо цифр в таблицу на странице выводились слова. Для 1 - 4 - "Включен", для 0 - "Выключен". Как можно проверить все поля?

**UPDATE:**

Есть таблицы, которые надо объединить, для того, чтобы в таблице хранить цифры, а выводить содержимое в виде слов. И это вызвало у меня затруднение, никак не могу придумать рабочий запрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да можно, но не так :-) а что значат _s.orders, s.news, s.other_? с какими полями они должны объединяться?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: эм, а как это у вас в одной колонке и `0` и `Выключен`?

Comment: Я хочу в первой таблице хранить, допустим, 0, а выводить на страницу слово "Выключен".

Comment: ну так вы показываете что у вас **в одной** таблице - одна строчка -**хранит название**, а другая **цифры**

Comment: Первую я забивал вручную - то как оно должно выглядеть, а вторая - то как получается. Не могу понять как хранить цифры, а выводить вместо них слова.

Comment: Скорректировал ответ, после дополнения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто через запятую перечислить поля в ON-условии не получится, для их объединения нужен оператор `AND` или `OR`

```
SELECT t.type_condition AS pay, t.type_condition AS orders, 
       t.type_condition AS news, t.type_condition AS other, 
       s.login AS login, s.telephone AS telephone
FROM `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
INNER JOIN `vixen_erps_services_type` t
ON t.type_id = s.pay AND
   t.type_id = s.orders AND
   t.type_id = s.news AND
   t.type_id = s.other
```

В `ON` действуют те же правила, что и после ключевого слова `WHERE`.

**UPDATE:**

Однако, в вашем случае, вам придется для каждого из полей выполнить `INNER JOIN` (я бы даже заменил его на `LEFT JOIN`)

```
SELECT
  p.type_condition AS pay,
  o.type_condition AS orders, 
  n.type_condition AS news,
  a.type_condition AS other, 
  s.login AS login,
  s.telephone AS telephone
FROM
  `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
LEFT JOIN
  `vixen_erps_services_type` p
ON
  p.type_id = s.pay
LEFT JOIN
  `vixen_erps_services_type` o
ON
  o.type_id = s.orders
LEFT JOIN
  `vixen_erps_services_type` n
ON
  n.type_id = s.news
LEFT JOIN
  `vixen_erps_services_type` a
ON
  a.type_id = s.other
```

Как вариант вам возможно подойдут вложенные запросы

```
SELECT
  (SELECT type_condition
   FROM vixen_erps_services_type
   WHERE type_id = s.pay) AS pay,
  (SELECT type_condition
   FROM vixen_erps_services_type
   WHERE type_id = s.orders) AS orders,
  (SELECT type_condition
   FROM vixen_erps_services_type
   WHERE type_id = s.news) AS news,
  (SELECT type_condition
   FROM vixen_erps_services_type
   WHERE type_id = s.other) AS other,
  s.login AS login,
  s.telephone AS telephone
FROM
  `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
```

Comment: тут скорее `OR` мне кажется

Comment: @Grundy, возможно. Привел AND чтобы продемонстрировать объединение нескольких условий в ON.

Comment: Работает как надо. Большое спасибо.