# Выборка из нескольких таблиц JOIN

Tags: php, sql, pdo, join

есть запрос

```
$myEvents = $db->execute("

SELECT e.* , u.name, u.lastname, u.tip FROM event e LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON (e.id_text = u.id ) WHERE  e.id_admin = :id_admin and e.id_when >= :timeNow ORDER BY e.id_when ASC

", $arrQuery );
```

как сделать выборку e.id_text = u.id и сюда добавить ещё e.id_foto = u.id

когда ставлю and не получается :(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй [Можно ли писать несколько условий в JOIN после ON?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536822/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-join-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-on)

Comment: Не работает, тут задача объединить две таблица стоит

Comment: ваш запрос с join и одним условием работает?

Comment: да, но он один столбец берёт . and пробовал не помогло, запятую тоже и скобками пытался объединить

Comment: изменил свой ответ :)

Comment: Он куда то пропал